# How to mutually exclude multiple arguments in Python's argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I've read through quite a few tutorials, questions and documentation and could not figure out how to achieve this:

```
prog.py [-h] [-d DEVICE -l | (-m M -s S -p P)]
```

When using the -l argument, prog.py reads from a device interface. When providing -m, -s and/or -p, prog.py writes to that interface. Reading and writing is not possible at the same time, so reading and writing arguments are mutually exclusive.

Once DEVICE has been specified, either -l or at least one of -m, -s or -p needs to be provided, it should also be possible to provide any combination of those three.

So far I approached this problem from various angles:

- I tried mutually exclusive groups which do not work as only single arguments can mutually exclude each other (please correct me if I'm wrong)
- I tried to set up sub parsers but I failed...

This is what I tried last:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d","--device",
        default="system",
        help="foo")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='foo')

read_parser = subparsers.add_parser('read', help='foo')
read_parser.add_argument("-l", "--list",
        action="store_true")

write_parser = subparsers.add_parser("write", help="bar")
write_parser.add_argument("-m","--mode",
        type=str,
        choices=["on","off","auto"],
        help="foo")
write_parser.add_argument("-s", "--season",
        type=str,
        choices=["winter","summer"],
        help="foo")
write_parser.add_argument("-p","--present",
        type=int,
        choices=[0,1],
        help="foo")
parser.parse_args()
```

This is not even close as with subparsers argparse expects either read or write. What I need to do is add groups that are mutually exclusive. Anyone has an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: I might replace `-l` with a subcommand `read` and add a (seemingly redundant) subcommand `write`. IMO, the best way to handle the requirement that at least one of a group of options be used is to just raise an error after parsing if `mode`, `season` and `present` are all `None`. Otherwise, you might define the `write` parser to take one more more "tagged" positional arguments from `m:on`, `m:off`, `m:auto`, `s:winter`, `s:summer` ,`p0`, and `p1` rather than strictly optional options.

Comment: I tried adding a subgroup to a mutually exclusive group, by calling `group.add_argument_group()`. That didn't work either. I'm not even sure if argparse has a concept of subgroups, or if groups are even supposed to have an `add_argument_group` method.

Comment: `argument_group` is only used in the `help` display.  `mutually_exclusive`group` is used during parsing, and in the `usage` formatting.  A MEG maybe placed inside an `argument_group` for `help` purposes.  But putting an AG in a MEG doesn't do anything useful.  MEG implement a simple `XOR` test, and nothing more complicted.  There's no nesting of groups beyond what I just described, nor any fancier logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on your own (with basic argparse functionalities) if correct arguments combination was passed:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-d","--device",
    default="system",
    help="foo")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list",
    action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-m","--mode",
    type=str,
    choices=["on","off","auto"],
    help="foo")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--season",
    type=str,
    choices=["winter","summer"],
    help="foo")
parser.add_argument("-p","--present",
    type=int,
    choices=[0,1],
    help="foo")
args = parser.parse_args()

# if user defines device but not any read/write argument raise exception
if args.device is not None and not args.list and all(arg is None for arg in (args.season, args.present, args.mode)):
    parser.error('Wrong arguments passed')

# if user defines read and write arguments at the same time raise exception
if args.list and not all(arg is None for arg in (args.season, args.present, args.mode)):
    parser.error('Wrong arguments passed')
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the most useful solution. Unfortunately though the help screen does not reflect these dependencies, but that's not a problem in this case.